# How can I add an item to "File menu" in VS Code?

Tags: menu, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I try to create an extension which add an item into the file menu.
For examples I use an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400280/how-to-add-context-menu-with-vscode-extension) from StackOverflow and an [article](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points) from code.visualstudio.com.

The article has the list:

- The global Command Palette - commandPalette
- The Explorer context menu - explorer/context
- The editor context menu - editor/context
- The editor title menu bar - editor/title
- The editor title context menu - editor/title/context
- The debug callstack view context menu - debug/callstack/context
- The SCM title menu - scm/title
- SCM resource groups menus - scm/resourceGroup/context
- SCM resources menus - scm/resource/context
- SCM change title menus - scm/change/title
- The View title menu - view/title
- The View item menu - view/item/context
- The macOS Touch Bar - touchBar

I sucsessfuly add an item to the context menu of the editor (and I have tried all of items from the list) but I do not understand how to add an item to the main menu (for example to the file menu).

P.S. A little investigation. In 2015 some user [asked](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/365) about adding a new item into top level menus. Then (as I understand it) developers added "*a new top level menu for extension commands*" (instead of ability to add a new item to any top level menu). It was in 2016. Then this top level menu dissappeared.

P.P.S. I have connect the user who asked about new menu item in 2015. He told me that as he know this functionality was not added.