# Add menu in VS Code Menu Bar

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, plugins, vscode-extensions

Is there any library available in visual studio code that allows extending the menu bar in visual studio code? Currently, I am only able to add my item in the editor context menu in vs code.

I need to add a separate menu item in the menu bar of the visual studio code. How can I do that?

If not then can we add a submenu item in any of the existing menus? Like if I could add an item in **Tools**?

Comment: here is the documentation on menus that extensions can contribute commands to: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus

Comment: @StephenRichter Already gone through this. Is there anything specific I can use from here?

Comment: I had the same question and could not find an answer. Related questions: [How to add a new menu item to the File menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56200303/) and [How can I add an item to "File menu"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54807777/)

Comment: it's better to create the custom item in the action bar (left verticle bar) instead of creating it in the menu bar (top horizontal bar). after that, build your things by extending the sidebar panel. you can find more related to this at: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview